# the Dirac-delta and derivatives

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima, dirac-delta

I do not understand the following sentence:

One can see the Dirac-delta at $x$, $\delta(s-x)=\delta_x(s)$ as *second* derivative of $(s-x)_ {+} = \max(0,s-x)$ or $(x-s) _ +=\max(0,x-s)$ depending on if one wants the primitives zero to the left or to the right.

Can someone kindly elaborate on this ?

Comment: $\max(0,s-x)$ is the primitive of a piecewise continuous function, do you see which one?

Comment: @reuns I can guess that **Sign** but I'm not sure at all. I even think that I'm false with this.

Comment: @user122424 That is not quite correct. The derivative "ramp" function $(s-x)_+$ (with respect to $s$) is $u(s-x)$, where $u$ denotes the [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), and the derivative of $u(s-x)$ is $\delta_x(s)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann My guess was not so bad, your `step function` looks like $\mathbf{Sign}$ somewhat shifted and scaled, am I right with this now ?

Comment: @user122424 Yes, that's correct about the sign and step functions. You correctly saw that there was a sudden increase in the slope, but you missed that the slope of the graph to the left of $s$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $(s-x)_+$ is a continuous function, $C^1$ except at $s=x$. Hence its derivative in the sense of distributions is the same a.e. as its pointwise derivative, that is
$$
\partial_s (s-x)_+ = \mathbf 1_{(x,\infty)}(s) = \mathbf 1_{(0,\infty)}(s-x),
$$
which is the function that is $0$ on $(-\infty,x)$ and $1$ on $(x,\infty)$. Taking once more its derivative in the sense of distributions gives since $\mathbf 1_{(0,\infty)}' = \delta_0$,
$$
\partial_s^2 (s-x)_+ = \delta_{x}(s) = \delta_{0}(s-x).
$$
Now the first point of the remark is that if you replace $s-x$ by $x-s$ it does not change the second derivative. Indeed, you will get $\partial_s (x-s)_+ = -\mathbf 1_{(-\infty,x)}(s) = -\mathbf 1_{(0,\infty)}(x-s)$, so here, it is different, there is an extra minus sign, but taking one more derivative cancels the minus sign by multiplying again by $-1$. Hence you again get $\partial_s^2 (x-s)_+ = \delta_{x}(s) = \delta_{0}(x-s)$.

Now one when doing the reverse process and taking primitives, the choice of the constant of integration will give different results. For example
$$
\int_{-\infty}^t \delta_x(\mathrm d s) = \mathbf 1_{(x,\infty)}(t)
$$
(this is a primitive that is $0$ on the left) while
$$
\int_{\infty}^t \delta_x(\mathrm d s) = -\int_t^{\infty} \delta_x(\mathrm d s) = -\mathbf 1_{(-\infty,x)}(t)
$$
(this is a primitive that is $0$ on the right). Integrating once more will give you
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\tau\int_{-\infty}^t \delta_x(\mathrm d s)\,\mathrm d \tau = (\tau-x)_+
\\
\int_{\infty}^\tau\int_{\infty}^t \delta_x(\mathrm d s)\,\mathrm d t = \int_\tau^{\infty}\int_t^{\infty} \delta_x(\mathrm d s)\,\mathrm d t = (x-\tau)_+
$$
where the first function is $0$ on the left of $x$ while the second function is $0$ on the right of $x$.

Comment: I have an elementary question. Is $(s-x)_+$ a function of $x$ or of $s$ ? One of these should be fixed and generally $x$ should be the variable. But you seem in the first line of your answer claim reverse: that the variable is $s$ and $x$ is kept fixed.

Comment: Yes, you can see $(s-x)_+$ as a function of $x$ or $s$ with the other one "fixed", or alternatively just see that as a two variable function. What is important is the fact that you indicate with respect to which one you are deriving. Indeed, in this case, I am doing the derivation with respect to $s$ (so if you prefer, you can think of it as the fact that $x$ is fixed and $s$ is the variable). The reason is due to your question. You wrote the "the Dirac delta at $x$" and "$\delta_x(s)$". Both are expressions suggesting that $s$ is the variable and $x$ is fixed.